# Excluding a directory name in a zsh recursive glob

Tags: zsh, wildcards, recursive

I'm running zsh on Linux under `setopt extended_glob ksh_glob glob_dots`. I'm looking for something easy to type on the command line, with no portability requirements. I'm looking at a source code tree, with no “weird” file names (e.g. no `\` in file names, no file name beginning with `-`).

Either of the following commands print the list of subdirectories of the current directory recursively:

```
find -type d
print -l **/*/
```

This is actually an svn checkout:

```
$ find -type d
./.deps
./.svn
./.svn/text-base
./.svn/prop-base
./.svn/tmp
./.svn/tmp/text-base
./.svn/tmp/prop-base
./.svn/tmp/props
./.svn/props
./lib/.svn
./lib/.svn/text-base
./lib/.svn/prop-base
./lib/.svn/tmp
./lib/.svn/tmp/text-base
./lib/.svn/tmp/prop-base
./lib/.svn/tmp/props
./src/.svn
./src/.svn/text-base
./src/.svn/prop-base
./src/.svn/tmp
./src/.svn/tmp/text-base
./src/.svn/tmp/prop-base
./src/.svn/tmp/props
```

I want to exclude the `.svn` directories and their subdirectories which are present in every directory. It's easy with `find`:

```
find -type d -name .svn -prune -o -print
```

Can I do this with a short zsh glob? Ignoring dot files comes close (I need to do it explicitly because I have `glob_dots` set):

```
print -l **/*(/^D)
```

But this isn't satisfactory because it hides the `.deps` directory, which I do want to see. I can filter out the paths containing `.svn`:

```
print -l **/*~(*/|).svn(|/*)(/)
```

But that's barely shorter than `find` (so what am I using zsh for?). I can shorten it to `print -l **/*~*.svn*(/)`, but that also filters out directories called `hello.svn`. Furthermore, zsh traverses the `.svn` directories, which is a bit slow on NFS or Cygwin.

Is there a convenient (as in easy to type) way to exclude a specific directory name (or even better: an arbitrary pattern) in a recursive glob?

Comment: Why would you spend some time finding out whether your files have or have not dashes or backslashes (and let other readers find out by themselves when they can't guarantee that) instead of just write the bulletproof right thing like `printf '%s\n' **/*` or `print -rl -- **/*`?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas In a script, sure. But on the command line, saving 4 characters is worth it. In my real-world situation, I didn't need to find out about file names, I already knew (build trees tend to have tame file names).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Zsh's extended glob operators support matching over `/` (unlike ksh's, even in zsh's implementation). Zsh's `**/` is a shortcut for `(*/)#` (`*/` repeated 0 or more times). So all I need to do is replace that `*` by `^.svn` (anything but `.svn`).

```
print -l (^.svn/)#
```

Neat!

Comment: This is a great answer — though it requires `setopt EXTENDED_GLOB`. Without it, you'll get `zsh: bad pattern: [...]`.

Comment: I'm having trouble applying your answer to my use case. I'm trying to match the set of `CMakeLists.txt` files scattered in various subdirectory, excluding all directories starting with `cmake-*` from being searched. I tried `(^cmake-*)**/CMakeLists.txt#`; it works, but it doesn't include the `CMakeLists.txt` in my working directory (i.e. it finds those located in subdirectories _exclusively_). How can I include it?
Thanks, and great answer!

Comment: @brainplot If you want to exclude `cmake-*` at any level, then like in my answer, use `(^cmake-*/)#CMakeLists.txt`. If you only want to exclude `cmake-foo/bar/CMakeLists.txt` but not `baz/cmake-qux/CMakeLists.txt`, you need a different approach: `**/CMakeLists.txt~cmake-*/*`.

Comment: @Gilles all the `cmake-*` folders I wanted to exclude are in my current directory and I wanted to exclude them all.
I tried your first solution and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

While `ksh93` globbing is nowhere near `zsh`'s even with the `globstar` option, in `ksh93`, it can be achieved with:

```
set -o globstar
FIGNORE='@(.|..|.svn)'
printf '%s\n' **/
```