# Zsh: source scripts recursively

Tags: scripting, zsh

I have `~/scripts/` folder that contains multiple subfolders with arbitrary directory levels.

This folder only for scripts that need to be sourced when start `zsh`, how to recursively source all files under its folder and its subfolders in an short and effective way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sourcing all non-hidden *regular* files in there, in collation order:

```
for f (~/scripts/**/*(N.))  . $f
```

I would suggest however that you name those files using a specific template like with a `.zsh` extension (and use `*.zsh` instead of `*` above) to avoid problems if there are backup files lying about in there for instance.

Or you could at least exclude some common ones like `file~`, `file.dpkg-dist`, `file.back`...:

```
set -o extendedglob
for f (~/scripts/**/^*("~"|dpkg-(dist|old|new)|.(tmp|back|bak))(N.))  . $f
```

etc.

Comment: `for f (~/scripts/**/^*("~"|dpkg-(dist|old|new)|.(tmp|back|bak)))(N.))  . $f`. With `.zsh` means `<..>s/**/^*.zsh("~"|dpkg<...>`?

Comment: @TuyenPham No, there is no sense in combining them like that. It's about using a whitelist vs a blacklist. The whitelist is `/*.zsh`, and the blacklist is `/^*("~"|dpkg<...>)`. It's safer to use a whitelist, but if you have naming requirements that don't allow for requiring files to end in `.zsh`, then you could at least opt for using a blacklist.

Comment: How to exclude a folder under `~/scripts/`? In case that the *.zsh files in that folder need to be sourced in order manually. Can't arbitrary source file under that folder. I tried `| folder/*` and `| folder/*.zsh`, both didn't work, I got `bad pattern` when trying doing that.

Comment: Okay, I got that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71884/256195